# Updating .edmx from database automatically

Tags: database, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am using ado.net entity data model to work with the database (database - first approach).
I have a model containing only views from specific database.

An application uses views stored in the database to retrieve data.

How to automatically regenerate (or modify) .edmx file when new views were created in the database? Without having to manually update model from database and recompiling the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by regenerating classes and map classes from scratch for the views on every program start up